# Is it possible to write parameterized android espresso UI test?

Tags: android, junit, android-espresso, ui-automation, parameterized-tests

When writing android espresso UI test, is it possible to write parameterized test which accepts data from two different json files to add list of items inside the app? 
I have seen parameterized tests that take two files and run same test code for junit test but couldn't find any references for android espresso UI test

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class LoginTest {

  @Parameterized.Parameter
  public String mUserName;

  @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 1)
  public String mPassword;

  @Parameterized.Parameters
  public static Collection<Object[]> initParameters() {
      return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            {"validUsername", "validPassword"},
            {"invalidUsername", "invalidPassword"},
            // or other initialization like json file input
      });
  }

// Tests using mUserName and mPassword

}
```

Then every Test will run with each element of you parameters array.

Comment: how can i initialize files inside initParameters? example, i have testData1.json and testData2.json

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the library https://github.com/google/TestParameterInjector , it is very convenient and the next evolution step of JUnit4 `Parameterized`.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but is this supported in `AndroidJUnit4`?

Comment: AFAIK it has issues, but from my experience, exactly one parameterized param (class property) works for one unit test class.